# Accessing the attempt counter for change in job behaviour

Tags: snakemake

I have a job that might fail with a specific configuration, what I want to do is let it run once and if it fails run a slightly different configuration.
I found the [attempt parameter](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#standard-resources) but I don't find a way to access it outside the resources tag...

do you know how to access it or any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the attempt counter is contained as argument "'--attempt' 'int'" to the jobscript (in my case a wrapper script in python)

therefore you can access it for example with:

```
sys.argv[sys.argv.index('--attempt')+1]
```

Comment: You probably can get something "cleaner" using `argparse`.